# How to Insert primary key in a table while using Play Framework, Ebean, sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, playframework

I want to insert a primary key in a table. How do I set the `"Identity Insert"` property ON from my Controller Class? I've tried this with no luck:

```
String sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT t_Student ON";

        Connection conn = play.db.DB.getConnection();
        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            try {
                stmt.execute(sql);
                student.save();
            } finally {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
```

Here, I want to save the `"student"` object in to the DataBase, but getting the error: `"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 't_Student' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."` Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

## One important thing.

`IDENTITY_INSERT` has nothing to `primary key` in database table. Moreover it has nothing to do with playframework in your situation. `Primary key` in shortcut is constraint that won't allow adding the same value to column(or columns). It's obvious. `IDENTITY_INSERT` mean that you take control explicitly of value for `PK` constraint. You're the boss.

 **For example:**

```
CREATE TABLE student (id int PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(40))
```

This situation simulates `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` and is very rare in database schema. Nevertheless it's rare, you need to expliclitly put `id` and `name`. You must be aware that current `id` won't interfere with existing primary keys in table:

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES(1,'John')
```

For first time this code will work but when you try insert it again it will raise exception because you want add the same value as `PK`.

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` in other hand allow you to forget inserting `id` each time because database engine will do it for you. It will also keep `PK` constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE student (id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(40))
```

And if you want insert row into table you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO student('Johny Paul')
```

And if you will force `ID`:

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES(666,'Johnny Rambo')
```

You will have exception: `An explicit value for the identity column in table 'student' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.` There are some situation when you need have full control of database values: `dictionary tables` across many environments or when your `PK` is corrupted and you need to "surgery" on PK. Otherwise don't use `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`. Perhaps under the hood EBean can't recognize whether insert statement should use id or not.

## Answer

I strongly suggest using table with `IDENTITY` (`IDENTITY_INSERT OFF`). I have used Ebean only few times (I don't like this database layer framework) but I think that code should help:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="student")  
public class Student {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    public String name;
}

Student student = new Student();
student.name = "Jonny JDK";
Ebean.save(student);
```

Or you can write raw SQL:

```
SqlUpdate insert = Ebean.createSqlUpdate("INSERT INTO student VALUES ('Jonny Bravo')");
insert.execute();
```